# Right to left in Liferay Portlet

Tags: html, css, jsp, liferay

I want to have right to left alignment in my portlet. It is ok when test it in a normal html page. But it is not right to left when I put it in a Liferay portlet and it shows left to right. Here is my code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.patientInfo
{
    direction:rtl;
    border:2px solid;
    width: 100%;
}
.titile
{
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-right:5px;

}
p
{   
    display:inline; 
}
.patientName
{
    background-color:#0CF;
    direction:rtl;
}
.doctorName
{
    background-color:#0CF;
    direction:rtl;  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="patientInfo">
<div class="patientName"><p class="titile">نام بیمار:</p><p> اکبر اسدی</p></div>
<div class="doctorName"><p class="titile">نام دکتر:</p><p>مریم اخیانی</p></div>
</div>
</body>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: have you checked if the HTML generated in the portlet is the same as in the simple web page? the portal container may be generating a different HTML from the expected.

Comment: When see the page source my code is without any changes. But this code is on the top of the page: <html class="ltr" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">.

Comment: I mean to run your portlet, open a navigator and see the HTML source generated there, check if your styles can be accessed and the HTML is similar to the one generated by your page alone.

Comment: Yes. The code is similar. Is there any configuration for language and direction in liferay?

Comment: Nope, is just same html. Another thing, when you're writing pages for a portlet, they should just contain html fragment, not an entire html page.

Comment: I removed any other htm fragment. But the problem did not solve. This is code is the only remaining code: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>. By the way css is included in jsp file.

Comment: I saved the generated code as a html file and opened it. It was ok

Answer (score 0):

Put the style sheets classes in separate css-file and register it in `liferay-portlet.xml`, so it will be loaded by Liferay. That is better way, becouse liferay cut the head-tag off.

liferay-portlet.xml:

```
<header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
```

Comment: the colors that I set in the style tag are applied and the direction tag is not applied. But I will test this.

Comment: I get this error while deploying: Error: Could not find or load main class com.liferay.portal.tools.SassToCssBuilder

Comment: the path is e.g. MyTest-portlet\docroot\css\main.css